# Le manque d’élision de « de ouf »

Tags: expressions, usage, prononciation, argot

Je suis conscient du fait que la construction « de ouf » est de l’argot, mais quoi qu’il en soit, c’est quelque chose que j’entends assez souvent dans mon quotidien. Ainsi, j’aimerais savoir la raison pour laquelle il n’y a pas d’elision. C’est-à-dire, selon ce que je sais, nous devrions entendre « d’ouf » normalement, cependant, j’entends clairement deux mots: « de » et « ouf ». Je me demande si ce n’est pas juste idiomatique, et c’est juste comme ça, ou s’il y a une autre raison.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tout vient de ce que le verlan fonctionne oralement à un niveau syllabique. Si nous disions "d'ouf", alors à l'envers, on entendrait "foud" car le son "d" serait pris dans la même syllabe que le mot "fou".

Donc seul le second mot doit être à l'envers pour que le terme d'origine soit reconnaissable : l'élision, en fusionnant les syllabes "de" et "ouf", créerait un autre mot lors de la traduction du verlan (foud).

Comment: J'ai déjà entendu c'est un truc d'ouf (en France). Donc ce n'est pas impossible.

Comment: Si le terme est bien connu sans l'élision, on peut se la permettre sans dommage, l'interlocuteur comprend de lui-même. Mais de fait, elle est plus rare, selon mon expérience (même si l'usage argotique est forcément variable en fonction des milieux et des générations...).

Answer (score 1):

*Ouf* n'est pas de l'argot, c'est du verlan. J'admets que certains m'objecteront que le verlan est une sorte d'argot. Soit. Mais il est important de ne pas oublier que c'est du verlan parce que ce qui fait que la plupart des gens ne font pas l'élision (et je ne la fais pas) c'est que le verlan n'affecte que le mot lui même et pas ce qui l'entoure.

On pourrait  dire aussi que c'est une expression idiomatique mais ça n'est pas en cause ici.

OK c'est un truc de ouf...

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu quelqu'un faire l'élision avec *ouf*. Pareil pour *uc* ([*J'en ai plein le uc d'être pris pour un con*](https://www.fishfish.fr/publication/post-plein-le-uc-d-etre-pris-un-con-au-prix-ou-on-paye-nos-sols-ils-pourraient-nous-les-vendre-rince-et-quand-ils-marquent-qu-il))

Comment: @jlliagre J'ai l'ai entendu de façon très localisé (un groupe de personnes) donc je ne voulais pas dire jamais. Le [wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/truc_d%E2%80%99ouf) donne « variant » mais on entend bien [dəuf] dans l'enregistrement. C'est vrai qu'en parlant vite on entend à peine le [ə].

Comment: Même si le [ə] peut être plus ou moins amuï, il me semble avoir toujours entendu une syllabe de plus que s'il s'était agi de la forme *d'ouf*.